# Heroku Scheduler Memory Quota Exceeded Constantly (Java Play)

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, scheduled-tasks

We are running a Java Play project on Heroku and have been getting endless Error R14 (Memory Quota Exceeded) on the Heroku/scheduler dyno all day.

heroku/scheduler.3831:  Process running mem=1058M(103.1%)

heroku/scheduler.3831:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

We currently have 5 daily jobs scheduled, but they all occur after business hours. For some reason though the Heroku/scheduler dyno is hitting memory quota caps all day, despite no jobs actually running.

The web dynos are working without an issue.  Has anyone encountered this issue with Heroku Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend lowering the max heap size on the scheduler process. Play is somewhat notorious for using lots of native (off-heap) memory (mostly because due to Netty I think). If you lower the heap size, it should allow more room for the native memory.

You can set the max heap size with an option like `-Xmx300m` on the `java` command that the scheduler runs.

Comment: Interesting, I will give that a try!  I guess I am a little confused as to why the heroku scheduler is running at all during the day, when all our jobs are scheduled at night.   If I limit the heap size on each job I can imagine that would help with memory usage for that specific job, but when the jobs shouldn't be running at all, I am a little unclear as to why I would still be getting these high memory usages.

Comment: If the scheduler is running when it's not supposed to, you should open a ticket at https://help.heroku.com. that seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bumping the dyno size for your scheduler job (ex: Standard-1X -> Standard-2X)